# Storeview not showing in 'Design->Configuration'

Tags: magento2

I have created another store view for French and change the default one to English. Now when I see it works on frontend, but French store view takes a lot of time to load and also theme is changed to default Luma theme. While for English store view its fine.

When I checked 'Design->Configuration', I didn't find 'French' store view in the list, while English is there.

Any suggestion why it is not listed?

Comment: You should go `Admin-> Stores-> All Stores`

Comment: @AnkitShah both store views are showing but their themes are different. I want them to use my own theme.  How I can change theme for storeviews?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok, I have solved it.

After adding new website, store or store view, the `design_config_grid` indexer need to run in order to show new entry inside `Content -> Design -> Configuration`

Comment: Great to hear :) Keep it up